# React Native Prevent Undefined Objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I am grabbing data from an API to display an image based on the API value. The following code works perfect IF there is an image in the object. If an API item does not have an image the app throws an "Undefined is not an object" error.

```
<View>
 <Image source={{uri:props.enclosures[0].url}} style={styles.mainPhoto} />
</View>
```

I have tried the following code to check if the value exists first, but it still throws exact same error if an API item does not have image.

```
<View>
{props.enclosures[0].url ?
 <Image source={{uri:props.enclosures[0].url}} style={styles.mainPhoto} />
 :
 <Text>No Image</Text>
}
</View>
```

Comment: Did you try condition : {props.enclosures ? <Image....

Comment: it seems your given code above should be just fine, the "Undefined is not an object" error is show when you are making API call can you show more details when you make API call?

Comment: @Oleg I tried this, it shows same error. props.enclosures is an object, is there any way to check if props.enclosures is an object first? The API call is being made in a previous screen and passed to this component

Comment: Did you try condition : {props.enclosure &&props.enosure.length ? <Image....

Comment: This worked: {props.enclosures && props.enclosures.length > 0 ?

Comment: In addition if you will remove all conditional image render, will you receive the error, if yes, your problem is not in this level/step.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to access multiple properties of a nested object, you should check everything, like so

```
<View> // Checking everthing so it never throws an error
    {props.enclosures && props.enclosures[0] && props.enclosures[0].url ?
     <Image source={{uri:props.enclosures[0].url}} style={styles.mainPhoto} />
     :
     <Text>No Image</Text>
    }
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent undefined error you can also use [path](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#path) from Ramda library. It allows you to safely access any nested object/array.

```
const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const apiImage = path(["enclosures", 0, "url"], props);
  return {
      <View>
         {apiImage ?
         <Image source={{uri:apiImage}} style={styles.mainPhoto} />
          :
         <Text>No Image</Text>
         }
      </View>  
  }
}
```